# Fieldpack 2.01 - Switch not working

Tags: switch, field-pack

I'am trying to create a new Field of type "Fieldtype - Switch", but I'am getting this error:

Unable to load requested field type file: ft.pt_switch.php.
Confirm the fieldtype file is located in the expressionengine/third_party/ directory

Which is weird, because the correct file should be ft.fieldpack_switch.php.

I had the old 1.x version installed, but I uninstalled everything and removed the files. My EE version is 2.6.

What can cause this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Fieldpack 2.02 fixed this problem.